# SQL Server Cursor Skips the IF condition inside While Loop (Scope of Cursor)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure where i am executing  this below code of Cursor,
This is my first time i am using cursor,

```
declare @Gold_Min int, @Gold_Max int, @Silver_Min int, @Silver_Max int, @Bronze_Min int, @Bronze_Max int, @gold_c int, @silver_c int, @bronze_c int;
set @gold_c = 0;
set @silver_c = 0;
set @bronze_c = 0;
set @Gold_Max = 100;
set @Gold_Min = 75;
set @Silver_Max = 74;
set @Silver_Min = 50;
set @Bronze_Max = 49;
set @Bronze_Min = 25;

DECLARE @ParticipantId int, @Transaction_date date, @Transaction_Time float, @Transaction_completed int, @gold int, @silver int, @bronze int;
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR DYNAMIC FOR
    select TransactionsCompleted, Gold, Silver, Bronze from #Gamification_Transaction_Per_Date
OPEN @MyCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
INTO @Transaction_completed , @gold , @silver , @bronze;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  /*
     YOUR ALGORITHM GOES BELOW   
  */
  while(@Transaction_completed > 0)
  begin
    if(@Transaction_completed >= @Gold_Min and ( (@Transaction_completed <= @Gold_Max) or (@Transaction_completed > @Gold_Max) ))
    BEGIN
        if(@Transaction_completed between @Gold_Min and @Gold_Max)
        BEGIN
            set @Transaction_completed = @Gold_Max - @Transaction_completed;
            set @gold_c = @gold_c + 1;
            break;
        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            set @Transaction_completed = @Transaction_completed - @Gold_Max;
            set @gold_c = @gold_c + 1;              
            break;
        END
    END
    if(@Transaction_completed >= @Silver_Min and ( (@Transaction_completed <= @Silver_Max) or (@Transaction_completed > @Silver_Max) ))
    BEGIN
        if(@Transaction_completed between @Silver_Min and @Silver_Max)
        BEGIN
            set @Transaction_completed = @Silver_Max - @Transaction_completed;
            set @silver_c = @silver_c + 1;
            break;
        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            set @Transaction_completed = @Transaction_completed - @Silver_Max;
            set @silver_c = @silver_c + 1;              
            break;
        END         
    END
    if(@Transaction_completed >= @Bronze_Min and ( (@Transaction_completed <= @Bronze_Max) or (@Transaction_completed > @Bronze_Max) ))
    BEGIN
        if(@Transaction_completed between @Bronze_Min and @Bronze_Max)
        BEGIN
            set @Transaction_completed = @Bronze_Max - @Transaction_completed;
            set @bronze_c = @bronze_c + 1;
            break;
        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            set @Transaction_completed = @Transaction_completed - @Bronze_Max;
            set @bronze_c = @bronze_c + 1;              
            break;
        END
    END
  end
     Update #Gamification_Transaction_Per_Date SET Gold = @gold_c WHERE CURRENT OF @MyCursor
     Update #Gamification_Transaction_Per_Date SET Silver = @silver_c WHERE CURRENT OF @MyCursor
     Update #Gamification_Transaction_Per_Date SET Bronze = @bronze_c WHERE CURRENT OF @MyCursor
  /*
     YOUR ALGORITHM GOES ABOVE
  */
  FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
  INTO @Transaction_completed , @gold , @silver , @bronze;
END; 

CLOSE @MyCursor ;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
```

END;

What my motive is to update values of **Gold** , **Silver** and **Bronze** Coins in a certain table named as **#Gamification_Transaction_Per_Date**

The Table structure is defined as : [The Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhIhY.png)

- The Main Query is that the If loop inside the While Loop is not executing while when i print 'HII I am here' outside the loop it works completely fine.
- The Expected Output is : [The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHikt.png)
- Any Leads would be really appreciated

Thanks & Regards
shohil Sethia

Comment: What is your expected output? You might not require loop/cursor in most of the cases

Comment: Hi @KannanKandasamy
Yes i might not require cursor,
The expected output is the updation of the table i have included with new number of Gold, Silver or Bronze badges.

Comment: Hi @KannanKandasamy, I have updated the question with Expected Output.

Comment: You might require to use MERGE with Insert/Update/delete based on your logic

Comment: Hi @KannanKandasamy,
I respect your knowledge,
Can you please suggest a solution with respect to the context of the question ?
Thank You

Comment: Taaags, SQL-Server or MySQL?

Comment: Hi @KtX2SkD
I have updated the tags,
Thanks for notifying,

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, I just skimmed this but, is it me or does he just want each row to be assigned the medal it deserves if it qualifies for one (*and there doesn't seem the possibility of more than one medal per row*), then he wants counts of how many were assigned of each medal?

Comment: @SHOHILSETHIA, may I ask what objective did the homework have stated, and what problem did you specifically run into while working on it?

Comment: Hi @KtX2SkD,
The output is a sample, There is no task to get the records with medals assigned,
The point was to update the records with medals the record deserves on basis of certain value, 
So i was thinking of parsing the table to update the table while parsing,
Since new to **sql-server** therefore **cursor** caught my eye,
The main motive was to serve this data whenever SP is called (Trigger) or in other terms update an application data in Real-Time whenever an  transaction is completed.
That's all

Thanks

Comment: Objective noted, though I would still like to know what problem you're having. Meanwhile, could you please explain the purpose of either of `( (@Transaction_completed <= @Gold_Max) or (@Transaction_completed > @Gold_Max) )` or `if(@Transaction_completed between @Gold_Min and @Gold_Max)`? I'm at a loss to what's their purpose. Thank you.